# CATextLayer - Set Kerning / Letter spacing

Tags: text, core-animation, core-text, kerning, catextlayer

How can I set the kerning of text on a CATextLayer?

I know it is possible with NSAttributed String but the text of my label changes very very often and I don't want to create a new NSAttributed String object every single frame.

Comment: You could have a CATextLayer for each character. Would you like to animate the kerning?